# XAML code review

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am totally new to 8.1 Store App in Visual Studio. Can any one help me what this below code means that comes with default Grid App template for Store app 8.1

```
<Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its nothing but the animation transition applied to the children of that grid when they appear on the screen. You can explore it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.transitions).